# How do I run DotNet as a Daemon on a MAC?

Tags: .net, macos, daemon

I have found a lot of resources on how to run dotnet as a Daemon on Linux and Docker. I know very little about Macs and so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Nobody uses macOS that seriously in this case, because most enterprise deployments are on either Windows Server or Linux machines.

But if you want your ASP.NET Core Worker Service project to run with macOS, you might

1. Follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service) on Windows to get familiar with the basics.
2. Use [the systemd package](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd) as your starting point to write a launchd package (such as `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Launchd`) for macOS (as [launchd is the standard there](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/terminal/apdc6c1077b-5d5d-4d35-9c19-60f2397b2369/mac)).
3. Go back to your work in step 1 and replace `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` with your `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Launchd` package.

Comment: It appears that Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Launchd does not exist.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesWoods You are supposed to write it out. Shouldn't be that hard as systemd and launchd do have similarities.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. I was looking for something that already existed before going down the road of custom writing my own solution.